# Foundation 4 : render custom select returned with ajax call

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm struggling trying to figure out how to render the custom form select in Zurbs Foundation 4, which has been returned with the ajax call. At the moment I'm simply re-initialising the plugin, but I know that's not the right way:

```
$(document).foundation('forms');
```

Also - the same question about resetting the select. Is there a way of doing it without actually hard code the id of the element as the object?

```
$('form select').trigger('change', true);
```

Comment: So the values of the select are populated by the ajax call?

Comment: that's correct - including the whole select element - consider this as country > regions, where after selecting the country the regions select is replaced with the list of relevant regions.

Answer (score 2):

You can fire foundation('forms') function just on parent container. For example, I have a modal window which contains a form loaded via ajax. The modal window has id="modal-region". To get custom fields in the form I do:

```
$('#modal-region').foundation('forms');
```